# Clicking "Done" on keyboard to dismiss keyboard, but it will not be dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to dismiss the keyboard by clicking the "Done" button but it will not be dismissed. Here is what I have done so far:

I have also added protocol `UITextFieldDelegate`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    texts.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    texts.delegate = self
    texts.keyboardType = .numbersAndPunctuation
    texts.returnKeyType = .done
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {   //delegate method
    var number = CGFloat((texts.text! as NSString).floatValue)

    slide.setValue(Float(number), animated: true)

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}
```

I want it to dismiss so that entered value can be stored in the `number` variable and the app can move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your `textFieldShowReturn` isn't being called since it has the wrong signature. Some quick use of the debugger (or a `print` statement) will confirm.

It should be:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // your code here
}
```

Note the `_` for the parameter label.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `.endEditing` to true should do the trick

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textfield: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}
```